# Will this cause a memory leak in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Will the unevaluated `putStrLn “hello”` create a space leak for every time `Func True` is called that will eventually consume all of my memory?

```
func bool = do if bool
                  then $ func True
                  else $ pure ()
               putStrLn "hello"
```

Comment: Yes, this will attempt to create an infinite `IO`, and I doubt the compiler will be able to optimise this away by flipping it around. Have you simply tried it?

Comment: @Bergi I haven't tried it yet because i just wanted to know if in theory it should cause one. Thanks for your answer

Comment: To be clear, are you asking whether this will just consume all of your CPU without doing anything, or whether it will consume all of your memory too? Or are you asking whether it will ever print "hello" rather than doing either of those things?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm only wondering if it will eventually consume all of my memory.

Comment: @Anon yes it will.  Run the program with -s flag. It will show memory usage stats when you quit